# Boost C++ libraries generating strange errors

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, libraries

I recently tried to write a c++ program, where I used the build in socket tools you can find in the Boost library. First of all, I tried to make a client/server based program, where the server just sends a message and the client receives it. It worked just fine.

Then I wrote another program, where I used a Xbox 360 kinect, to control my movement. The idea of creating the first program, was the get the code for the socket creating, so I can connect with, i.e. my Samsung tv, to control the tv, using my kinect.

The problem arises, when I copy my code from the first program, into my second program with the kinect. All of sudden, the program gives 100+ error, when compiling the boost library.

I triple checked the including libraries and all, but the problem still arises. Some of the errors are posted below:

```
 1>C:\boost_1_55_0b1\boost/asio/detail/socket_types.hpp(96): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'
 1>C:\boost_1_55_0b1\boost/asio/detail/socket_types.hpp(96): error C2238: unexpected  token(s) preceding ';'
 1>C:\boost_1_55_0b1\boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp(2224): error C2653: 'Windows' : is not a class or namespace name
 1>C:\boost_1_55_0b1\boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp(2224): error C2871: 'Collections' : a namespace with this name does not exist
 1>C:\boost_1_55_0b1\boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp(2225): error C2653: 'Windows' : is not a class or namespace name
 1>C:\boost_1_55_0b1\boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp(2225): error C2871: 'Networking' : a namespace with this name does not exist
 1>C:\boost_1_55_0b1\boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp(2226): error C2653: 'Windows' :  is not a class or namespace name
1>C:\boost_1_55_0b1\boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp(2226): error C2871: 'Connectivity' : a namespace with this name does not exist
1>C:\boost_1_55_0b1\boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp(2227): error C2065: 'IVectorView' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\boost_1_55_0b1\boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp(2227): error C2065: 'HostName' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\boost_1_55_0b1\boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp(2227): error C2059: syntax error : '>'
1>C:\boost_1_55_0b1\boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp(2227): error C2653: 'NetworkInformation' : is not a class or namespace name
1>C:\boost_1_55_0b1\boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp(2228): error C2065: 'hostnames' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\boost_1_55_0b1\boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp(2228): error C2227: left of '->Size' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>          type is ''unknown-type''
1>C:\boost_1_55_0b1\boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp(2230): error C2065: 'HostName' : undeclared identifier
```

And many many others. I know by the fact, that the libraries work. It worked in the first program, so I just can't figure out what's causing the problem.

Other includes are the SDL and SDK for Kinect libraries for c++.

Comment: Check whether some of the non-boost headers you include #define one of the following macros: `in4_addr_type` `u_long_type` `s_addr`.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this too. I found by adding the "/P" option to the C++ compiler options in Visual Studio and recompiling the file that failed, that `s_addr` was indeed getting #defined.

The offending header was part of the Windows SDK `inaddr.h`, which is included in the header chain of `winsock.h`.

The offending line in the header was:
`#define s_addr  S_un.S_addr`

More information about this header is on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556972%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The fix I found was to `#undef s_addr` just before the #include of the BOOST ASIO header.